# do I put the <itunes:new-feed-url> tag in the old feed or the new one when switching to a new podcast service?

Tags: itunes, podcast

I keep finding conflicting posts of people having the same issue. One person says they put the  in the old feed, whereas others are saying they put it in the new feed. Any ideas?

What exactly does this tag do? I've read some posts that say it lets iTunes update the feed in iTunes?

Any info would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A podcast client which reads a feed with the <itunes:new-feed-url> tag will update its subscription for that podcast so it uses the URL from the tag.

From [the spec](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390):

> Use the <itunes:new-feed-url> tag to manually change the URL where
>   your podcast is located. This tag is only supported at a
>   <channel>level (podcast).

So at the *old* feed location you want **either**:

A feed with the <itunes:new-feed-url> tag pointing to the new feed location. (Tag is in the old feed.)

**OR**

A HTTP 301 redirect to the new feed, which contains the <itunes:new-feed-url> tag pointing to the new feed location. (Tag is in the new feed.)

The latter is [Apple's prescribed method](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itca489031e0):

> 1. Set your web server to return an HTTP 301 redirect response when it
>      receives a request for the old feed.
> 2. Use the <itunes:new-feed-url> tag in your new feed to point to the new URL.